# Jpa Repository in Spring boot app findBy issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create `findBy` JpaRepo it's about returning only the data where `isDeleted` attribute is `false`.

this is my **Service** :

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers =  cutomerRepository.findByIsDeletedFalse();
    return customers;
}
```

and this is my **Controller** :

```
@GetMapping("/viewList")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        customers = customerService.getAllCustomers();
        if (customers.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("no content ");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
    LOGGER.info("calling list of customers");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(customers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and this is customer model :

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private long serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

but when I run it in postman it's not working and return an error :

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not
> exist: boolean = integer   Hint: No operator matches the given name
> and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 315

***How could I solve this issue?***

Comment: Please share your repository definition.

Comment: And what is the _is_deleted_ DB column type defined in the actual table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the name for your query isn't created right.

However, in this case, the usage of `@Query` will be much clearer.

***Code snippet***:

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    List<Customer> findAllByIsDeletedIsFalse();
    
    @Query("from Customer c where c.isDeleted=false")
    List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
}
```

Iinstead of:

> cutomerRepository.findByIsDeletedFalse()

You missed one more `Is` at the name of the method.

---

Update your Domain:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private Long serialNumber;
    // ...
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;
}
```

JPA fields should be Objects instead of primitives. And entity class should implement ***Serializable*** as well.

If the exception will be the same you could try to update `@Query`:

> @Query("from Customer c where c.isDeleted=0")

---

If pure SQL works for your DB you could use native query:

```
@Query(
  value = "select * from Customer where is_deleted = false",
  nativeQuery = true)
List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
```

Comment: that causes an error :

Comment: `Cutomer is not mapped [from Cutomer c where c.is_deleted=false]`

Comment: it's the same error as i submitted in the question

Comment: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: still the same in all cases, same error

Comment: What about pure SQL. Have you tried to write select query by yourself? And how it behaves?

Comment: I updated the question and submit the whole table

Comment: Try to writ select query with `where is_deleted = false`.

Comment: it worked and return data :\

Comment: yeeeeees !! Finally it worked !! thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because it doesn't follow the naming conventions for a boolean field. Usually in Java the primitive booleans are named without `is` prefix and the getter would be using this `is` prefix.

So in your case your entity class should look like that:

```
public class Customer {
    // ...
  
    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean deleted;

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

}
```

Also the naming of the spring repository method should be:

```
List<Customer> findAllByDeletedIsFalse();
```

In case you want to use a `Boolean` reference type you can name your field `isDeleted`, but then the class would look like that:

```
public class Customer {
    // ...

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

}
```

and the repository method:

```
 List<Customer> findAllByIsDeletedIsFalse();
```

Comment: still same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Boolean Java maps a `bit` datatype column. You are probably using `int` as datatype in your database.

Comment: no i'm really not :\ all data coulmn data taype as false and true